# Read XML files with Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xmldom

I need to read a XML file with java. File structure as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml_tool xmlns:md="http://www.example.com/XT/1.0/">
    <md:header>
        <md:application_version>1.0</md:application_version>
        <md:export_date>19-04-2012</md:export_date>
        <md:export_time>14:55</md:export_time>
        <md:export_user>USER01</md:export_user>
    </md:header>
    <md:table table_name="CUSTOMER" key="customer number" record_count="2" column_count="5">
        <md:record>
            <md:column name="customer_number">123456</md:column>
            <md:column name="reg_date">01-04-2012</md:column>
            <md:column name="customer_name">Test Customer</md:column>
            <md:column name="customer_type">Normal </md:column>
            <md:column name="comments">This is a test record</md:column>
        </md:record>
        <md:record>
            <md:column name="customer_number">555111</md:column>
            <md:column name="reg_date">02-04-2012</md:column>
            <md:column name="customer_name">Test Customer</md:column>
            <md:column name="customer_type">VIP </md:column>
            <md:column name="comments">This is a test record</md:column>
        </md:record>
    </md:table>
</xml_tool>
```

I have read [How to read XML file in Java – (DOM Parser)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) example and try to do my work. But I'm unable to read XML file successfully.

My Code

```
    try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("c:\\file.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("md:record");

        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) node;

                System.out.println(getTagValue("md:column", eElement));


            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

            Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

        return nValue.getNodeValue();
      }
```

and Result is

```
123456
555111
```

How could I read this XML file?

Comment: Maybe you can further elaborate on '...i'm unable to...'. What have you tried and what does not work (code)?

Comment: Unfortunately your update did not make your question more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your for  loop...

```
for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++)
{
      Node node = nList.item(i);
      if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
      {                 
             if(eElement.hasChildNodes())
             {
                 NodeList nl = node.getChildNodes();
                 for(int j=0; j<nl.getLength(); j++)
                 {
                     Node nd = nl.item(j);
                     System.out.println(nd.getTextContent());
                 }
             }
       }
}
```

Comment: got `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element` at `       Element el = (Element) nl.item(j);`

Comment: Check the updated answer. You also dont need `getTagValue()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're doing very inexact queries (namely, `getElementsByTagName(...)`, which is not restricted to first-level descendants). In `getTagValue(...)`, you'll need to iterate over the `NodeList` in order to get all the data for all of the children--in which case, maybe you intend for the method to return a `List<String>`. Or, better yet, move that `NodeList` to your other method and loop over it there.

To get all the data, including the header, you will need to recursively iterate over all the elements, starting with the root node.

That said, there's a much better way. You can use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) to bind your XML schema to your POJO (plain-old Java object) data model. Then all the loading will be done automatically, and you can concentrate on the program logic.